# Как сделать проверку на соответствие в django

Tags: python, django, django-model, django-template

Подскажите пожалуйста пример того как можно реализовать проверку в djano где сравниваются данные из двух моделей.

- Есть модель заводa - Manufacture который выпускает молочку(творога, молоко, сливки) - поле product
- в этих продуктах мы определяем жирность - модель Fat, поле fat_value.
- И есть у нас потенциальные покупатели - модель Customer, у которых жирность нормируется по ГОСТ. допустим customer_name = 'Солнышко', fat_max = 15.
  Можно ли каким-то образом организовать проверку что-бы при жирности продукта меньше fat_max у покупателя выводилось имя покупателя в шаблон? Ниже приведена схема моих моделей.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

каким образом должен выглядеть мой views.py чтобы это сработало?

```
def index(request):
    product_list = Manufacture.objects.all()
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(fat_max__gte=item.fat)
    context = {
        'product_list':product_list,
        'customer_list':customer_list
        }
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то на странице где у Вас отображается модель Fat
нужно отфильтровать покупателей

```
customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(fat_max__gte=item.fat)
```

где `item` - это экземпляр объекта `Fat`, отображаемый на текущей странице
И затем нужно передать полученный `customer_list` в контекст шаблона для вывода

Подробней о различных фильтрах можно прочитать в официальной документации
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: не могу переформатировать вывод , никак не соображу . Мне нужно определить функцию def fat_detail(request, pk):  в ней получить экземпляр жира item = Fat.objects.get(pk=pk)  и уже на основе этого делать представление в шаблоне?